# How characters and integers are stored in Python

Tags: python

I am aware that in C, characters are 1 byte, and ints are 4 bytes. When I run this code in Python to determine the storage of characters and integers, I get unexpected values. Could anyone explain this discrepancy?

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(1)
24
>>> sys.getsizeof(10)
24
>>> sys.getsizeof(100)
24
>>> sys.getsizeof("a")
38
>>> sys.getsizeof("b")
38
>>> dump = cPickle.dumps(1)
>>> sys.getsizeof(dump)
41
>>> >>> sys.getsizeof(chr(65))
38
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?  It's best to avoid worrying about how Python types map to numbers of bits and bytes, unless you have a specific reason to do so.  Python types are specified in terms of an API defining what you can do with them, not in terms of a specific implementation at the byte level.

Comment: @BrenBarn i need to worry how its mapping, i need to know.

Comment: Why do you need to know? What are you going to do with this information?

Comment: just for knowledge, like in C i know about it

Comment: This depends on the implementation. for example, in pypy if the JIT compiler decides a variable can be a C int, it would use 4 bytes

Answer (score 1):

First off Python has no character type, those are strings containing one character. Second, there is additional overhead for the PyObject header, though some base types only use part of it.

Comment: yes it takes as object but it must have to deal with char and int, that's i am not aware of it.

Comment: No, there is nothing in Python that would map to the char type (aside from the stuff in CFFI specifically to interface with C code).

Comment: it must, for example, everything in computer is either 0 and 1, but python dosent  take everything in 0 and 1, it map compiler does the task. so you cant just leave the base :)

Comment: I don't even know what that means, but the fact remains that Python has nothing like a one-byte number type, be it for numbers or ASCII characters. Python has (in various ways depending on version) byte arrays and Unicode code point arrays.

Comment: @Hackaholic on that basis why don't you write everything in machine language? Python, like all programming languages, provides *abstractions* so you don't need to worry about the electrons and silicon. Also, there are different implementations of Python - pick one (e.g. the standard CPython) and start looking at the source code if you really want to know what's happening underneath.

Answer (score 0):

I can understand Hackaholic's curiosity.
In C, each int has a fixed number of memory. Each unsigned char must use one byte. Each short must use two bytes...
In python, int is not a primitive data type. It is a class instead. So it has its member functions and its member data.

Try the following:

```
import sys
a=pow(2,32)
print('a:', a)
print(type(a))
print(sys.getsizeof(a))

b=pow(2,63)
print('b:', b)
print(type(b))
print(sys.getsizeof(b))

c=3
print('c:', c)
print(type(c))
print(sys.getsizeof(c))
```

The result:

```
a: 4294967296
<class 'int'>
32

b: 9223372036854775808
<class 'int'>
36

c: 3
<class 'int'>
28
```

Although a,b, and c are all int. They have different memory size.
The memory it uses depends on your data. So for int, the minimum is 28 bytes because its members other than the data itself also occupy space.

Comment: yes - in the docs for [sys](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof),
it specifies that `Only the memory consumption directly attributed to the object is accounted for, not the memory consumption of objects it refers to.`